# How to set a drop down item to be shown by default

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hide, show

I have a page with several a vertical dropwdown list where you click on the item to dropdown all the info about that certain topic, see picture:

[image]

How can I set the dropwdown to be open by default ? So instead of being on hide when the page opens, it is set to show?

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: If you are using javascript to show your dropdown, I suppose it has a display:none css before you hover it? If it is so, set it to display:block and you are good to go.